# Cursor for-loop gives unpredictable results

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

When I execute the sql, the query gives proper result set. But when I use it inside a cursor forloop it says "Not a GROUP BY expression"

```
    DECLARE
v_sum_of_strength number :=0;
BEGIN
for i in (select to_char(time,'MM-YYYY') "stick" ,count(*) usage from my_view group by to_char(time,'MM-YYYY')
order by substr(to_char(time,'MM-YYYY'),6), substr(to_char(time,'MM-YYYY'),1,2))
LOOP

select sum(strength) into v_sum_of_strength from batch where substr(to_char(startdate,'MM-YYYY'),1,2)<=(substr('04-2022',1,2)) AND substr(to_char(enddate,'MM-YYYY'),1,2)>=(substr('04-2022',1,2));

--dbms_output.put_line(i.candle);
dbms_output.put_line(v_sum_of_strength);
dbms_output.put_line('------------------');

END LOOP;
END;
```

Please see the session print

```
DECLARE
    v_sum_of_strength number :=0;
    BEGIN
    for i in (select to_char(time,'MM-YYYY') "stick" ,count(*) usage from my_view group by to_char(time,'MM-YYYY')
    order by substr(to_char(time,'MM-YYYY'),6), substr(to_char(time,'MM-YYYY'),1,2))
    LOOP

    select sum(strength) into v_sum_of_strength from batch where substr(to_char(startdate,'MM-YYYY'),1,2)<=(substr('04-2022',1,2)) AND substr(to_char(enddate,'MM-YYYY'),1,2)>=(substr('04-2022',1,2));

    --dbms_output.put_line(i.candle);
    dbms_output.put_line(v_sum_of_strength);
    dbms_output.put_line('------------------');

    END LOOP;
    END;
Error report -
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
ORA-06512: at line 4
ORA-06512: at line 4
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: Please show the full error stack. It may be coming from the view instead the loop rather than your cursor.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try using sub-strings to filter dates. Instead, you can use `TRUNC(time, 'MM')` in the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses and it allows you to simplify the order (and will order correctly across century boundaries):

```sql
DECLARE
  v_sum_of_strength NUMBER;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN (
    SELECT TRUNC(time,'MM') AS "stick",
           COUNT(*) AS usage
    FROM   my_view
    GROUP BY TRUNC(time,'MM')
    ORDER BY TRUNC(time,'MM')
  )
  LOOP
    SELECT sum(strength)
    INTO   v_sum_of_strength
    FROM   batch
    -- This is what your code does but I'm not sure it is what you intend.
    -- WHERE  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM startdate) <= 4
    -- AND    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM enddate)   >= 4
    -- This is, I think, what you intend.
    WHERE  startdate <  DATE '2022-05-01'
    AND    enddate   >= DATE '2022-04-01';

    --dbms_output.put_line(i.candle);
   dbms_output.put_line(v_sum_of_strength);
   dbms_output.put_line('------------------');
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ugmqC7yl)

Answer (score 0):

Works OK for me:

```
SQL> create table my_view as select sysdate time from dual;

Table created.

SQL> create table batch as select 100 strength, sysdate startdate, sysdate enddate from dual;

Table created.

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> DECLARE
  2    v_sum_of_strength number :=0;
  3  BEGIN
  4    for i in (select to_char(time,'MM-YYYY') stick ,
  5                     count(*) usage
  6              from my_view
  7              group by to_char(time,'MM-YYYY')
  8              order by substr(to_char(time,'MM-YYYY'),6),
  9                       substr(to_char(time,'MM-YYYY'),1,2)
 10             )
 11    LOOP
 12      select sum(strength)
 13        into v_sum_of_strength
 14        from batch
 15        where substr(to_char(startdate,'MM-YYYY'),1,2) <= (substr('04-2022',1,2))
 16          AND substr(to_char(enddate,'MM-YYYY'),1,2)   >= (substr('04-2022',1,2));
 17      --dbms_output.put_line(i.candle);
 18      dbms_output.put_line(v_sum_of_strength);
 19      dbms_output.put_line('------------------');
 20    END LOOP;
 21  END;
 22  /
100
------------------

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

Please, demonstrate the error the way I did, by copy/pasting your session.

Comment: I have attached the session print in my question. Your script is working on mine. But I dont see any difference at all between our scripts. Thanks :)

Comment: Do queries `select * from my_view` and `select * from batch` work?

Comment: Yes they are working

Comment: No idea, then. Could you post several sample rows from MY_VIEW and BATCH?

Comment: I formatted it and it worked. Maybe some whitespace character issue. Thanks again :)

Comment: Who knows; I'm glad you made it work.